# System fonts not fected properly

Tags: javascript

I have different fonts installed on my machine.Suppose there is a font "Arial" present.
If I try to retrieve "Arial Bold" font that specific font not being retrieved instead "Arial Regular" fetched.
I used to reinstall that font on machine and it works fine.
But Whenever machine get restarted same issue get replicated.
Please suggest.

Comment: How is this a javascript issue? At least, how does it pertain to your code...specifically javascript?

Comment: instead of machine fonts you can use web fonts for that

Answer (score 1):

The name should be "Arial Black", not Arial Bold.

Unless you want to *bold* the regular Arial, in which case you use a style property for:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Comment: I understand that `font-weight: bold` might cause psuedo-bold to be used instead of a properly-designed bold typeface. I'd use this with caution.

Comment: The problem is not with changing the font style its about fetching right file from system fonts.

Comment: True @Dai. Fonts are a problem on web, coming to specific designs, as they differs depending on operating systems and what the user has installed. Although, most fonts handles bold correctly, at least the most common available fonts for web. There could be more problems in regard to hinting and grid-fitting. Of course, a web-font would be a better choice for a specific design, but other problems could arise (ie. support for web-fonts itself).

Comment: @user1584122 ok, try to change the font-family name to "Arial Black". Please note that though it works under Windows the font will most likely be substituted under a different OS.

Comment: @Abdias Software I am windows user. I am not able to fetch specific font file but if reinstalled the same font it works fine.What can be the problem?Please suggest.

Comment: I am a little unsure of what you are trying to achieve - Could you please post some code to describe the problem better? I assume you are not trying to load the font-file itself (as a file) using javascript, but instantiating the font-face from the Arial Black font? And why do you need to reinstall, do the installed font file get removed form the fonts folder when you try to load it/or after?